# How to fix - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'forget' or attribute 'forget_pack' in tkinter gui app

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, screen, attributeerror

i'm writting a tkinter gui app that has a main.py. In main.py i call functions that display diferent screens regarding what goes next. All my functions are located in functions.py. I have imported functions.py in main.py.

The code from main.py goes like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import functions

functions.login()
```

The functions.login() after submitting the info calls another login_click(). If the login data is ok, gui shows another screen - admin screen. That other screen is also a function admin_screen().

I was trying to hide the first screen by adding a function:

```
def hide_main_screen():
     login.forget_pack()  #or login.forget() 
     admin_screen()
```

This hide_main_screen() is invoked inside login_click() like this:

```
def login_click():
    global name
    global password
    name=e_usn.get()
    password=e_pass.get()
    if name=="" or password =="":
        messagebox.showwarning('Warning!', 'No data.')
    elif name=='admin' and password=='12345':
        print('Login OK')
        hide_main_screen()      
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Login Error!', 'Username or password are false.')
```

I was trying the enter another gui screen (admin screen) and hiding the first (login screen).

My error is shown as:

File "d:\PyFlora\functions.py", line 71, in hide_main_screen
login.forget_pack()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'forget_pack'

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. The tkinter method you're looking for to hide widgets that have been added to the GUI with the `pack()` geometry manager is `pack_forget()`, not `forget_pack()`
2. `pack_forget()` will only work on tkinter widgets, and only if they have been `pack`ed (that is, `pack_forget()` doesn't work on widgets added with `place()` or `grid()`)

`pack_forget()` won't work on your `login` *function*, because it's not a tkinter widget.

If you have a *window* that you want to hide, i.e. a `Toplevel` object, you can simply `destroy()` it when you no longer need it. If you have individual *widgets* that you've `pack`ed and want to hide, you can use `pack_forget()`.